# Executing function in file js after insert DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html page.

load file script.js

```
function myFunction() { 
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.async = true;
  s.src = 'http://demodomain.com/script.js';
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x); 
} 
    myFunction();
    abc(); // => Uncaught ReferenceError: abc is not defined
```

In file script.js

```
function abc() {
alert('a');}
```

I want :
Executing function abc() in main page.
Can someone help me how I can do that?

Comment: define it in script.js and execute it in script.js or in the main page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this function be executed as soon as it is loaded, then why don't you simply call that method while defining it

```
(function abc() 
{
   alert('a');
})();
```